# Another way to write multiple LIKE clauses in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to run a query to search for emails in a database. However, it seems the query I have written will only accept one LIKE clause. When I add multiple LIKE clauses, it gives back the jsonify Exception error I have written "No tickets found", when tested with Ajax. What is another way I can write multiple LIKE clauses in one query?

Comment: Stackoverflow suggested both tags. Is this question really of no value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the multiple LIKE but with the multiple parameters.
`EmailSearchStr = """SELECT * FROM emails WHERE body LIKE %s OR subject LIKE %s"""` has two %s in it, so execute is expecting two arguments. 
This should work:

```
q.execute(EmailSearchStr, ("%" + search_string + "%", "%" + search_string + "%"))
```

By the way - the exception returned would have told you exactly what went wrong - but you obfuscated it with

```
except Exception, e:
    return jsonify(error = 'No tickets found')
```

Be more specific with the exception caught by "except", it will help you debugging and is a better practice.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. It still gave the same error, no Syntax errors were indicated.

Comment: @JustinBaxtron Can you remove the wrapping try-except and provide the exact exception you're recieving?

Comment: error: "Search module not executed successfully (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE subject LIKE '%%the%%'' at line 1")"     I tried searching for the word 'the'.

Comment: can you provide q._executed?

Comment: I added the Ajax query into the question post.